# Should I normalize the target data the same way as the input data?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

This is the way I'm currently transforming my input data

```
x_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
training_x = x_scale.fit_transform(training_x)
testing_x = x_scale.transform(testing_x)
validation_x = x_scale.transform(validation_x)
```

Should I be processing the target data the same way?

```
y_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
training_y = y_scale.fit_transform(training_y)
testing_y = y_scale.transform(testing_y)
validation_y = y_scale.transform(validation_y)
```

If my activation is linear and error is mse, is this way of normalization correct?

Comment: Check this out: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_transformed_target.html